# Does iPad mini 4 also feature the new and faster 2nd-Generation Touch ID sensor featured in the iPhone 6s?

Tags: ipad, touch-id, iphone

After I read on multiple websites that the new **2nd-Generation Touch ID sensor** in the **iPhone 6S** is a lot faster, I was wondering if the new **iPad mini 4** features the same sensor.

Basically, I'm not interested if it is a new sensor (as I am not sure whether the improvement is due to new hard- or software), but rather if it reacts as fast in the **iPad mini 4** as in the **iPhone 6S**.

Comment: "Basically, I'm not interested if it is a new sensor, but rather if it reacts as fast in the iPad mini 4 as in the iPhone 6S." Actually, unless the actual Touch ID sensor is improved in the iPad Mini (4th Generation), like replacing it with the 2nd-Gen one found in the iPhone 6S, unlocking your iPad using it won't be all that faster. So, you're really very interested in if uses the new sensor.

Comment: BTW, the new sensor is so fast that if you want any hope of seeing new notifications before it opens, you have to use the side button, or a non-registered finger. It's actually a bit **too** fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have both and can confirm that the iPad Mini 4 **does not** have the iPhone 6S TouchID Sensor. Side by side the iPad feels more like the iPhone 6 where you have to pause on the button to authenticate. Quite disappointing.

Answer (score 2):

Apple's iPhone 6s website has a section about Touch ID on the [Technology](http://www.apple.com/iphone-6s/technology/) page. It says:

> Touch ID lets you unlock your phone and make purchases with Apple Pay simply by using your ﬁngerprint. It uses highly sophisticated algorithms to recognize and securely match your ﬁngerprint. And the improved Touch ID sensor detects your ﬁngerprint even faster than the previous generation.

By comparison, the iPad mini 4 has a whole page about [Touch ID](http://www.apple.com/ipad-mini-4/touch-id/), but it never references a previous generation that's been improved upon. That leads me to think that the iPad mini 4 doesn't share the iPhone 6s's Touch ID 2 technology.